# How do I parse string response in api.ai?

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

While creating Intents in Api.ai, I can parse sys or user parameters as listed here:
https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-entities#section-user-entities

However if I have to parse a string response, there isn't a way to add that as a parameter. Any workaround to parse a string response from user to fetch an entity?

Like for e.g., 
Customer's name is John.
I want to retrieve John in my action.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can utilize api.ai ***Contexts*** to Achieve that..

check [Context documentation](https://docs.api.ai/docs/guidelines-contexts)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , It is possible.

1)First you should set the output context in `intent` from which you want to fetch customer's name
e.g. [setting output context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CitR.png)

2) Then define the input context with `same name` in `intent` where you want to get your customer's name e.g. [setting input context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6xo7.png)

3) then you can access name by defining the parameter with `#<context_name>.<parameter_name>` e.g. #send.name

Hope this might help!!